# Perform matrix multiplication with cosine similarity function

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, gensim, word2vec, cosine-similarity

I have two lists:

```
list_1 = [['flavor', 'flavors', 'fruity_flavor', 'taste'],
          ['scent', 'scents', 'aroma', 'smell', 'odor'],
          ['mental_illness', 'mental_disorders','bipolar_disorder']
          ['romance', 'romances', 'romantic', 'budding_romance']]

list_2 = [['love', 'eating', 'spicy', 'hand', 'pulled', 'noodles'],
          ['also', 'like', 'buy', 'perfumes'],
          ['suffer', 'from', 'clinical', 'depression'],
          ['really', 'love', 'my', 'wife']]
```

I would like to compute the cosine similarity between the two lists above in such a way where the cosine similarity between the first sub-list in list1 and all sublists of list 2 are measured against each other. Then the same thing but with the second sub-list in list 1 and all sub-lists in list 2, etc.

The goal is to create a **len(list_2) by len(list_1) matrix**, and each entry in that matrix is a cosine similarity score. Currently I've done this the following way:

```
import gensim
import numpy as np
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('./data/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', binary=True) 
similarity_mat = np.zeros([len(list_2), len(list_1)])

for i, L2 in enumerate(list_2):
    for j, L1 in enumerate(list_1):
        similarity_mat[i, j] = model.n_similarity(L2, L1)
```

However, I'd like to implement this with matrix multiplication and no for loops.

My two questions are:

1. Is there a way to do some sort of element-wise matrix multiplication but with `gensim's n_similiarity() method` to generate the required matrix?
2. Would it be more efficient and faster using the current method or matrix multiplication?

I hope my question was clear enough, please let me know if I can clarify even further.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two problems in code, the second last and last line.

```js
import gensim
import numpy as np
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('/root/input/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', binary=True) 
similarity_mat = np.zeros([len(list_2), len(list_1)])

for i, L2 in enumerate(list_2):
    for j, L1 in enumerate(list_1):
        similarity_mat[i, j] = model.n_similarity(L2, L1)
```

Answers to you questions:
1. You are already using a direct function to calculate the similarity between two sentences(L1 and L2) which are first converted to two vectors and then cosine similarity is calculated of those two vectors. Everything is already done inside the n_similarity() so you can't do any kind of matrix multiplication.
If you want to do your own matrix multiplication then instead of directly using n_similarity() calculates the vectors of the sentences and then apply matrix multiplication while calculating cosine similarity.
2. As I said in (1) that everything is done in n_similarity() and creators of gensim takes care of the efficiency when writing the libraries so any other multiplication method will most likely not make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Those bugs aren't relevant to the question about using matrix multiplication though. They are good feedback on the code, but the question is about using matrix multiplication (which is possible, contrary to the answer). See example below.

Comment: I think the question was if it is possible to optimize the code with n_similarity() by performing matrix multiplication and not just perform matrix multiplication. What you are doing is creating BOW (vectors) and then using them for cosine similarity but everything is already taken care in the gensim model so forcefully doing everything from scratch is not optimization. And **I have mentioned that you can do matrix multiplication** but its not worth it.

Comment: No, you're missing the optimisation below. It is the nested for loops that are being optimised out using matrix multiplication, not the similarity calculation on a vector-by-vector basis. This optimisation would significantly improve the time on two large datasets with multiple comparisons. Gensim only optimises the interior calculation, not the multiple comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach, but it's not clear from the question whether you understand [the underlying mechanics of the calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity), which might be causing the block.

I've changed the input strings to give more exact word matches, and given the two strings different dimensions to make it a bit clearer:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import numpy as np

list_1 = [['flavor', 'flavors', 'fruity_flavor', 'taste'],
         ['scent', 'my', 'aroma', 'smell', 'odor'],
         ['mental_illness', 'mental_disorders','bipolar_disorder'],
         ['romance', 'romances', 'romantic', 'budding_romance']]

list_2 = [['love', 'eating', 'spicy', 'hand', 'pulled', 'noodles'],
          ['also', 'like', 'buy', 'perfumes'],
          ['suffer', 'from', 'clinical', 'depression'],
          ['really', 'love', 'my', 'wife'],
          ['flavor', 'taste', 'romantic', 'aroma', 'what']]

cnt = CountVectorizer()

# Combine each sublist into single str, and join everything into corpus
combined_lists = ([' '.join(item) for item in list_1] +
                  [' '.join(item) for item in list_2])
count_matrix = cnt.fit_transform(combined_lists).toarray()

# Split them again into list_1 and list_2 word counts
count_matrix_1 = count_matrix[:len(list_1),]
count_matrix_2 = count_matrix[len(list_1):,]
match_matrix = np.matmult(count_matrix_1, count_matrix_2.T)
```

Output of match_matrix:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

You can see that the 1st string in `list_1` has 2 matches with the 5th string in `list_2`, and so on.

So the first part of the calculation (the dot product) has been calculated. Now we need the magnitudes:

```
magnitudes = np.array([np.linalg.norm(count_matrix[i,:])
                       for i in range(len(count_matrix))])
```

Now we can use matrix multiplication to turn that into a matrix of divisors (we need to reshape magnitudes into n x 1 and 1 x n matrices for this to produce an n x n matrix:

```
divisor_matrix = np.matmul(magnitudes.reshape(len(magnitudes),1),
                           magnitudes.reshape(1,len(magnitudes)))
```

Now since we didn't compare every single sublist, but only the list_1 with the list_2 sublists, we need to take a subsection of this divisor matrix to get the right magnitudes:

```
divisor_matrix = divisor_matrix[:len(list_1), len(list_1):]
```

Output:

```
array([[4.89897949, 4.        , 4.        , 4.        , 4.47213595],
       [5.47722558, 4.47213595, 4.47213595, 4.47213595, 5.        ],
       [4.24264069, 3.46410162, 3.46410162, 3.46410162, 3.87298335],
       [4.89897949, 4.        , 4.        , 4.        , 4.47213595]])
```

Now we can calculate the final matrix of cosine similarity scores:

```
cos_sim = match_matrix / divisor_matrix
```

Output:

```
array([[0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.4472136],
       [0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.2236068, 0.2      ],
       [0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ],
       [0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.2236068]])
```

**Note these scores differ from the example given, since in the example every cosine similarity score would be 0.**